# Segment URI redirect laravel

Tags: redirect, uri, laravel, segment

I have the following URI:

```
http://localhost/testcart/products/cpa/1
```

where

```
cpa = URI::segment(2)
1 = URI::segment(3)
```

After post how do i redirect back to this URL.

I have tried

```
return Redirect::to('products/'.URI::segment(2).'/'.URI::segment(3))

return Redirect::to(URL::current())
```

None seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about return `Redirect::back()`

Comment: Awesome glad I could help this was my first answer with Stack Overflow :)